# Android : clicks on items included in the rows of a ListView not detected properly

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, listener

I have got a listView. Every row contains different items (let's say a TextView and an ImageView).

I set a OnClickListener on the TextView and another one on the ImageView in order to perform a specific action in case of click on one of these two items.

My problem is that the clicks on these items are not detected in a reliable way. I have to click several times in order to enter the OnClickListener.

Anybody already had this kind of problems ?

Thanks !

Comment: have u also added click listener on the listview? share the code. :)

Comment: I answered a similar question to this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700768/ontouchlistener-adding-to-all-list-elements-instead-of-only-one/22702896#22702896

Answer (score 0):

Have you setted this param in xml?

You should define on all of the child objects in the item listview (TextView, ImageView etc.):

android:clickable="false"
   android:focusable="false"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

And for the root item RelativeLayout / LinearLayout and so, define:

android:clickable="false"
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
   android:focusable="false"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"